# QPrinter output to pdf is not equivalent to the paper/page size (A4)

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qprinter

I am trying to output a QWidget ui to a pdf file like this;

```
const QString filename = "class1bills.pdf";

printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer->setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer->setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer->setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer->setFullPage(false);
printer->setOutputFileName(filename);

painter = new QPainter(printer);

class1Bill->render(painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QWidget::DrawChildren | QWidget::DrawWindowBackground);

painter->begin(printer);
painter->end();

assert(QFile::exists(filename));
```

`class1Bill` is an object of the class that inherits QWidget. Everything works fine but when i open the pdf file, i expect the widget ui to appear fitting the A4 page size but it appears very small that i didn't even see it at first glance. How do i make the widget ui fit the A4 paper size i set?

Comment: I see `printer->setFullPage(false);` - shouldn't that be true to fit to paper size ?

Comment: I'm glad, i'll put that in an answer so you can accept ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `printer->setFullPage(true);` in order to fit paper size

Comment: Same issue happens on pyqt5, this answer sadly doesn't fix it.